# How to write a Future method in foreach concisely

Tags: scala, twitter4j, twitter4s

I'm a beginner in Scala. Is there a concise way to write the following nested case statement?

```
def delete(
  client : TwitterRestClient,
  userId : Long,
  keyword : String) : Unit = {
client.userTimelineForUserId(userId).onComplete{
  case Success(value) => {
    value.data.filter(_.text.contains(keyword)).foreach(x => {
      client.deleteTweet(x.id).onComplete{
        case Success(value) => println(s"Success: $value")
        case Failure(exception) => println(s"Fail: $exception")
      }
    })
  }
  case Failure(exception) => println(s"Fail:$exception")
}
```

Comment: I strongly suggest returning the `Future` from this method (using `flatMap` and `Future.sequence` as described below) and handling errors at the next level up. This, in turn, may be able to pass the error up again until it gets to a layer that knows how to deal with it!

Comment: Thank you for the great advice. I'd like to change the return type of method to Future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slightly different way using `flatMap`, sequencing `Futures` and using `collect` instead of `filter` and `map`:

```
def delete(
  client : TwitterRestClient,
  userId : Long,
  keyword : String) : Unit = {

  client
      .userTimelineForUserId(userId)
      .flatMap(ratedData => Future.sequence(ratedData.data.collect {
        case tweet if tweet.text.contains(keyword) => client.deleteTweet(tweet.id)
      }))
      .onComplete {
        case Success(value) => println(s"Success: $value")
        case Failure(exception) => println(s"Fail: $exception")
      }
}
```

I have only compiled the code, dint run it.

Comment: Thank you for showing me the sample code.  It worked correctly.